# How should I convert a double sink to a single sink?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, remodeling

We are going to remodel our bathroom which currently has two sinks (and not that much cabinet/drawer storage) to a single sink with larger (and more) drawers for storage.

Under the current double sink, the setup is two large cabinets with a 9 inch bank of drawers between totaling about 60 inches wide. Each sink has its own water supply and drainage.

My questions are around changing this to a single sink setup.
Do I simply cap one set of supply and drainage? Can I do that inside the wall, so it is not under my new cabinets at all? Do I need to tee the two supplies and drains into one? I'd like to do this myself and it doesn't seem to hard, but should I just hire a plumber?

I had to take two photos and splice together. There is a bank of drawers (not shown) between each sink cabinet. As you can see the supply and drainage are into the wall.

[image: Two Bathroom sinks side by side]

Comment: Can you post pictures?

Comment: I'll take a couple tonight

Comment: gonna make a difference if drains and supplies come thru the floor or the wall.

Comment: Are you opposed to simply capping the lines right at the shutoffs?  You may find a use for them in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have absolutely no problems capping one set inside the wall. What a great DIY project (: